# Better way to write this query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created the following query to essentially combine stores into particular groups. Those groups are CDJR, CDJRF, ANP, and FARMER. This is the most efficient way I can think of making this query. Do you know a faster and less code driven query? I'm just learning how to be a more efficient query writer and any input would be appreciated. Please read beneath the query for more specifics. Please note, I added only 4 storecodes for simplicity. Let me know if you need anymore information.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(D.storecode) AS StoreCount,
        D.storeid,
        D.storename,                    
        D.storecode,                    
        D.start,                    
        D.organizationid,
        CASE
            WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 25, 19, 20, 26, 29, 30) THEN 'CDJR'
            WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (21, 23, 28) THEN 'FARMER' 
            WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid = 22 THEN 'ANP' 
        END AS BrandGroup
    FROM 
        store AS D                                              
        JOIN organization AS BO     ON D.organizationid = BO.organizationid
        JOIN franchises AS F        ON D.storeid= F.storeid
        JOIN franchisetype AS FT    ON F.franchisetypeid = FT.franchisetypeid   
    WHERE
        BO.countryid = 6            -- USA only.
        AND D.end IS NULL           -- Active stores.
        AND FT.active IS TRUE       
        AND F.end IS NULL           -- Active franchises.
        AND D.franchised = 'F'
        AND D.trainingtypeid = 1
        AND D.storemarket = 'M'
        AND D.storecodes IN (45660, 45733, 54816, 60739)
    GROUP BY
        D.storeid,
        D.storename,                    -- Dealer name detailed.
        D.storecode,                    -- Dealer code.
        D.start,
        D.organizationid,
        CASE
            WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 25, 19, 20, 26, 29, 30) THEN 'CDJR'
            WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (21, 23, 28) THEN 'FARMER' 
            WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid = 22 THEN 'ANP' 
        END
),
CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
        CTE
    EXCEPT
    SELECT *
    FROM
        CTE
    WHERE
        storecount <= 4
        AND brandgroup = 'CDJR'
),
CTE3
AS
(
    SELECT
        'CDJRF' AS FranchiseGroup,
        storeid,
        storename,
        storecode,
        start,
        organizationid
    FROM
        CTE2
    GROUP BY
        storeid,
        storename,
        storecode,
        start,
        organizationid
    HAVING
        COUNT(storecode) >= 2
    UNION
    SELECT
        BrandGroup,
        storeid,
        storename,
        storecode,
        start,
        organizationid
    FROM
        CTE2
    WHERE
        storecode NOT IN
            (
                SELECT
                    storecode
                FROM
                    CTE2
                GROUP BY
                    storecode
                HAVING
                    COUNT(storecode) >= 2
            )
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE3
```

Results:
FranchiseGroup; StoreID; StoreName; StoreCode; Start; OrganizationID

1. "CDJR";520;"Parker's Market";"05002";"1954-11-24";1336
2. "FARMER";763;"Joe Murphy's Farm";"23355";"1980-04-24";1579
3. "ANP";80549;"A&P";"69069";"2011-04-25";283224
4. "CDJRF";623;"Kraggers";"09733";"1952-01-24";1439

In the first CTE, example below, I pull store data, count it, and case the type IDs to go into 3 groups initially, not 4. Results to the CTE are provided below the CTE query.

```
SELECT 
            COUNT(D.storecode) AS StoreCount,
            D.storeid,
            D.storename,                    
            D.storecode,                    
            D.start,                    
            D.organizationid,
            CASE
                WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 25, 19, 20, 26, 29, 30) THEN 'CDJR'
                WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (21, 23, 28) THEN 'FARMER' 
                WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid = 22 THEN 'ANP' 
            END AS BrandGroup
        FROM 
            store AS D                                              
            JOIN organization AS BO     ON D.organizationid = BO.organizationid
            JOIN franchises AS F        ON D.storeid= F.storeid
            JOIN franchisetype AS FT    ON F.franchisetypeid = FT.franchisetypeid   
        WHERE
            BO.countryid = 6            -- USA only.
            AND D.end IS NULL           -- Active stores.
            AND FT.active IS TRUE       
            AND F.end IS NULL           -- Active franchises.
            AND D.franchised = 'F'
            AND D.trainingtypeid = 1
            AND D.storemarket = 'M'
            AND D.storecodes IN (45660, 45733, 54816, 60739)
        GROUP BY
            D.storeid,
            D.storename,                    -- Dealer name detailed.
            D.storecode,                    -- Dealer code.
            D.start,
            D.organizationid,
            CASE
                WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 25, 19, 20, 26, 29, 30) THEN 'CDJR'
                WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (21, 23, 28) THEN 'FARMER' 
                WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid = 22 THEN 'ANP' 
            END
```

Results:
StoreCount; StoreID; StoreName; StoreCode; Start; OrganizationID; BrandGroup

1. 1;80549;"A&P";"69069";"2011-04-25";283224;"ANP"
2. 2;763;"Kraggers";"23355";"1980-04-24";1579;"CDJR"
3. 1;763;"Kraggers";"23355";"1980-04-24";1579;"FARMER"
4. 7;623;"Joe Murphy's Farm";"09733";"1952-01-24";1439;"CDJR"
5. 1;623;"Joe Murphy's Farm";"09733";"1952-01-24";1439;"FARMER"
6. 6;520;"Parker's Farm";"05002";"1954-11-24";1336;"CDJR"

The second CTE, CTE2, removes the irrelevant CDRJ. Results are below the query.

```
CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
        CTE
    EXCEPT
    SELECT *
    FROM
        CTE
    WHERE
        storecount <= 4
        AND brandgroup = 'CDJR'
```

Results:
StoreCount; StoreID; StoreName; StoreCode; Start; OrganizationID; BrandGroup

1. 6;520;"Parker's Farm";"05002";"1954-11-24";1336;"CDJR"
2. 1;80549;"A&P";"69069";"2011-04- 25";283224;"ANP"
3. 1;623;"Joe Murphy's Farm";"09733";"1952-01-24";1439;"FIAT"
4. 7;623;"Joe Murphy's Farm";"09733";"1952-01-24";1439;"CDJR"
5. 1;763;"Kraggers";"23355";"1980-04-24";1579;"FIAT"

The last CTE, CTE3, combines the CDRJF result with the other groups after I count how many there are. The results all lead to the first set of results at the top of the page.

```
SELECT
    'CDJRF' AS FranchiseGroup,
    storeid,
    storename,
    storecode,
    start,
    organizationid
FROM
    CTE2
GROUP BY
    storeid,
    storename,
    storecode,
    start,
    organizationid
HAVING
    COUNT(storecode) >= 2
UNION
SELECT
    BrandGroup,
    storeid,
    storename,
    storecode,
    start,
    organizationid
FROM
    CTE2
WHERE
    storecode NOT IN
        (
            SELECT
                storecode
            FROM
                CTE2
            GROUP BY
                storecode
            HAVING
                COUNT(storecode) >= 2
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

The good

1. Your query is well formatted and readable.
2. You recognized that it wasn't as efficient as it could be.

The bad

1. Sample data not well formatted and easy to use.

The main problem is just with simplifying the logic. This is untested (see bad point #1), but it may give you an idea of how to clean it up.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(storeCode) OVER 
                            ( PARTITION BY  storeid,
                                            storename,
                                            storecode,
                                            start,
                                            organizationid

                            ) >= 2 THEN 'CDJRF'
                     ELSE BandGroup
                 END,
                storeid,
                storename,
                storecode,
                start,
                organizationid
           FROM (
                SELECT 
                    COUNT(D.storecode) AS StoreCount,
                    D.storeid,
                    D.storename,                    
                    D.storecode,                    
                    D.start,                    
                    D.organizationid,
                    F.BrandGroup
                FROM 
                    store AS D                                              
                    JOIN organization AS BO     ON D.organizationid = BO.organizationid
                    JOIN (SELECT store_id,
                                 CASE
                                      WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 25, 19, 20, 26, 29, 30) THEN 'CDJR'
                                      WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid IN (21, 23, 28) THEN 'FARMER' 
                                      WHEN F.storefranchisetypeid = 22 THEN 'ANP' 
                                  END AS BrandGroup,
                                 end
                            FROM franchises
                         ) F
                      ON D.storeid= F.storeid
                    JOIN franchisetype AS FT    ON F.franchisetypeid = FT.franchisetypeid   
                WHERE
                    BO.countryid = 6            -- USA only.
                    AND D.end IS NULL           -- Active stores.
                    AND FT.active IS TRUE       
                    AND F.end IS NULL           -- Active franchises.
                    AND D.franchised = 'F'
                    AND D.trainingtypeid = 1
                    AND D.storemarket = 'M'
                    AND D.storecodes IN (45660, 45733, 54816, 60739)
                GROUP BY
                    D.storeid,
                    D.storename,                    -- Dealer name detailed.
                    D.storecode,                    -- Dealer code.
                    D.start,
                    D.organizationid,
                    F.BrandGroup
                ) CTE
         WHERE storeCount > 4
            OR bandGroup <> 'CDJR'
    ) SUB;
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Did you mean to comment this to the question?

Comment: Err, yes. Deleted.